# Python efficient lookup structure for dynamic subsets?

Tags: python, dictionary, set, immutability

I'm trying to have constant-time lookup for values associated with the subsets of some given set, where order is not guaranteed.

I'll be actively working with the original set, removing / adding back elements, and would like to look up associated values of the remaining elements as I go along.

For example, if my given set is `given = {1, 2, 3}`, maybe I'd build a dict that looks like this...

```
{
    frozenset([]): 'apple',
    frozenset([1]): 'orange',
    frozenset([2]): 'ice bear',
    frozenset([3]): 'peach',
    frozenset([1, 2]): 'grizzly',
    frozenset([2, 3]): 'pear',
    frozenset([1, 3]): 'panda',
    frozenset([1, 2, 3]): 'banana',
}
```

Suppose I remove an element from the given set via `given.remove(2)`, leaving me with `{1, 3}`, and I wanted to see the associated value. I'd have to coerce my set to frozenset in order to look it up in the dict and retrieve the value `'panda'`. Consequently, if I add back the element via `given.add(2)`, restoring the original `{1, 2, 3}`, I'd again have to coerce to frozenset before retrieving `banana` from the dict.

I feel like having to coercing to a frozenset is an O(n) operation that defeats the purpose of an O(1) lookup.

Is there a way to more efficiently implement this sort of lookup in Python? Or are there any data structures that can help me out here?

I'm on Py2.7 but if Py3 is better for this, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It's `O(n)` where `n` is the size of the key set, not the size of your dictionary, which is an important difference. How big are these sets? In any case lookup in a dictionary still requires hashing the key which is bound to be `O(n)` as well.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that's absolutely right. I was thinking about this the wrong way. The sets are pretty large, but yes theoretically the hashing itself has to traverse the length of the key as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I feel like having to coercing to a frozenset is an O(n) operation that defeats the purpose of an O(1) lookup.

It's linear in the size of `given`, not in the size of the dict. For comparison, taking the hash is also linear in the size of `given`, so even if you didn't have to construct a frozenset, you'd still have the same asymptotic complexity.

If this cost is too expensive for you, you can try writing your own set wrapper class with a hash function that allows incremental updates, and break the usual condition that hashable objects not be mutable in ways that affect their hash value. I've personally had good results with a scheme based on [Zobrist hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing), where elements of the set are assigned hash codes generated at random that persist for the lifetime of the program, and the hash of the set is the XOR of all element hashes. When an element is added or removed, the set's hash can be updated by XORing it with the element's hash.

Comment: Ah yes. Linear to the size of the key, not the dict. Thanks for this, makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Based on user2357112's answer. Untested because I lost interest.

```
from random import Random

class FastRehashableSet(set):
    _initial_hash = 12345

    def __init__(self, seq=()):
        super(FastRehashableSet, self).__init__(seq)
        self._hash = self._initial_hash
        for x in seq:
            self._hash_single_value(x)

    def _hash_single_value(self, val):
        # Introduce extra randomness since the intended elements are ints
        # which just return themselves when hashed
        self._hash ^= Random(hash(val)).randrange(4294967296)

    def __hash__(self):
        return self._hash

    def add(self, elem):
        super(FastRehashableSet, self).add(elem)
        self._hash_single_value(elem)

    def remove(self, elem):
        super(FastRehashableSet, self).remove(elem)
        self._hash_single_value(elem)

    def discard(self, elem):
        change = elem in self
        super(FastRehashableSet, self).discard(elem)
        if change:
            self._hash_single_value(elem)

    def pop(self):
        val = super(FastRehashableSet, self).pop()
        self._hash_single_value(val)
        return val

    def clear(self):
        super(FastRehashableSet, self).clear()
        self._hash = self._initial_hash

    # You get the idea, I'm not doing these

    def update(self):
        raise NotImplemented

    def intersection_update(self):
        raise NotImplemented

    def difference_update(self):
        raise NotImplemented

    def symmetric_difference_update(self):
        raise NotImplemented
```

Answer (score 0):

What about coding the indice of the words in a list in binary from the list of element :

```
words = ["apple","orange","ice bear","peach","grizzly","panda","pear","banana"]

def get_indice(L):
    return sum(2**(i-1) for i in L)

# initial serie of elements
serie = [1,2,3]

# first computation of indice
ind = get_indice([1,2,3])

print serie,words[ind]

# remove the 2
val = 2
serie.remove(val)
ind -= 2**(val-1)

print serie,words[ind]

# add the 2
val = 2
serie.append(val)
serie = sorted(serie)
ind += 2**(val-1)

print serie,words[ind]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3] banana
[1, 3] panda
[1, 2, 3] banana
```

Note that the first computation cost N operations where N is the number of elements in serie which is better than the number of elements in words. The following operation of adding and removing are direct and cost O(1).

As the removing of the element in serie can cost some according to https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity . Maybe it is better to just invoke directly get_indices anyway.